# Mocking a class object using Mockito and PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Is it possible to mock a class object using Mockito and/or PowerMockito?

Something like:

```
Class<Runnable> mockRunnableClass = mock(Class<Runnable>.class);
```

Comment: Yes... That tells me how to mock a final class, but it doens't tell me how to mock the Class object.

Comment: `PowerMock.createMock(Class.class)`

Comment: Java generics use type erasure, so `Class<Runnable>.class` is incorrect. `Class` is `final`, but you can use PowerMock anyways.

Comment: What is your use case in that you want to mock "Class"?  Class is pretty common - just curious.

Comment: @veer Ok, I'll try that out tomorrow.  Cool, thanks.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002 I'm writing a test for a class which calls newInstance() on a class object.  It's a weird edge case.

Comment: You could refactor your class so that the newInstance call is in a method by itself, then use a Mockito spy as the object that you actually test.  Override just the method that has the newInstance call, in the object under test.

Comment: Unfortunately refactoring's not an option.  I didn't write the original code.

Comment: Then what happens if your testing reveals a bug?  You're not allowed to fix it?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I misread your previous comment. I was under the impression Mockito wasn't supposed to be used in this way. From the Mockito docs: "Spying on real objects is often associated with 'partial mocking' concept. However, Mockito spies are not partial mocks. Mockito spy is meant to help testing other classes - not the spy itself. Therefore spy will not help if you intend to verify if method calls other method on the same object. In this case I suggest being OO/SRPy (for example you might extract new class/interface...)"

Comment: +1 to @DavidWallace regarding ability to change/fix code.  What's the point of testing it if you can't change the code? If you can't/don't want to use a spy, you could inject a factory object that instantiates new objects.  Then you could mock the factory easily enough, right?

Comment: Yes, @jhericks, you could certainly inject a factory and mock it.  Using a spy would be simpler though.  And it WILL help - it surprises me that helixed claims that the documentation says otherwise.

Comment: I don't claim the documentation says so, it does.  I was quoting from it.  Mockito isn't intended to support partial mocking. Also, I never said I couldn't change the code to fix a bug. Fixing a bug and changing a class's interface are two very different things. The second impacts any users of the class and forces them to rewrite their code. You don't know the full context of what I'm doing, so please don't dismiss me when I say refactoring isn't an option.

Comment: You could make the refactoring that I suggested, without changing any of the interfaces that the class implements.  I'm happy to help you with this if you'd like me to.  I'm completely certain that it can be done in a way that's entirely compatible with your existing code.  Also, the Mockito team have actually put a lot of effort into providing a number of variants of partial mocking in recent versions.  To say that Mockito isn't intended to support partial mocking sells their efforts short, in my opinion. (I am on the Mockito team, but I am speaking for myself, not speaking as a team member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to mocking Class might be to use a Factory instead.  I know you are concerned about refactoring, but this could be done without changing the public API of the class.  You haven't provided much code to understand the class you are trying to test, but here's an example of refactoring without changing the API.  It's a trivial class, but it might give you an idea.

```
public class Instantiator {

  public Runnable getNewInstance(Class<Runnable> runnableClass) throws Exception {
    return runnableClass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

Of course, the easiest thing to do to test this trivial class would be to use a genuine Runnable class, but if you tried to mock the Class, you would run into the problems you're having.  So, you could refactor it thus:

```
public class PassThruFactory {
  public Object newInstance(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    return clazz.newInstance();
  }
}

public class Instantiator {
  private PassThruFactory factory = new PassThruFactory();

  public Runnable getNewInstance(Class<Runnable> runnableClass) throws Exception {
    return (Runnable)factory.newInstance(runnableClass);
  }
}
```

Now Instantiator does exactly the (trivially simple) thing it was doing before with the same public API and no need for any client of the class to do any special injecting of their own.  However, if you wanted to mock the factory class and inject it, that's very easy to do.

Comment: Good call on using the factory.

Comment: How will you test PassThruFactory class ?
Are you suggesting to ignore testing PassThruFactory class ?

Comment: Difficult to talk about this with such trivial examples, but you could test PassThruFactory without mocking anything.  You pass in a class and assert that you get an object of that type.

Answer (score 2):

why not using an agent if you can't refactor the code there isn't many options, as @jherics mentionned, java system classes are loaded by the bootstrap classloader and powermock can't redefine their bytecode.

However Powermock now coms with an agent, that will allow system classes mock. Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) for complete explanation.

The main idea is to modify your java command and add :

```
-javaagent: path/to/powermock-module-javaagent-1.4.12.jar
```

The basic thing this agent is doing is to definalize classes, to allow future mocking in a specific test, that's why you'll need to use specific types to communicate with the agent, for example with JUnit :

```
@Rule PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule(); // found in the junit4 rule agent jar
```

TestNG is also supported. Just check the [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) for more information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This looks like it could work, but our bootstrapping process is very complicated.  Modifying the Java agent isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

First, as stated in the comments, you would need to do:

```
Class<Runnable> mockRunnableaClass = (Class<Runnable>)mock(Class.class);
```

But that won't work in the usual way because of a limitation with PowerMock.  You cannot simply mock classes in from java.lang, java.net, java.io or other system classes because they're loaded by Java's bootstrap classloader and cannot be byte-code manipulated by PowerMock's classloader.  (See [PowerMock FAQ](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/FAQ) #4.)  As of PowerMock 1.2.5, you can work around this.  If the class you wanted to test was this:

```
public class ClassToTest {
  private Class<Runnable> runnableClass;

  public void setRunnableClass(Class<Runnable> runnableClass) {
    this.runnableClass = runnableClass;
  }

  public Runnable foo() {
    return runnableClass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

Then you would do this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ClassToTest.class }) // Prepare the calling class for test
public class SystemClassUserTest {

  @Test
  public void testFoo() throws Exception {
    Class<Runnable> mockClass = (Class<Runnable>) mock(Class.class);
    Runnable mockRunnable = mock(Runnable.class);

    ClassToTest objectUT = new ClassToTest();
    objectUT.setRunnableClass(mockClass);

    when(mockClass.newInstance()).thenReturn(mockRunnable);
    assertThat(objectUT.foo(), is(sameInstance(mockRunnable);
  }
}
```

Comment: The above doesn't quite work.  When I call `PowerMockito.mock(Class.class)`, the test runner throws an instance of `IllegalAccessError`.

Comment: I didn't actually test it, so it's possible that `Class` is too fundamental to mock.  What version of PowerMock are you using?

Comment: 1.4.10 I believe. I'm afraid you might be right. This might be one of those cases where it's just not possible to cleanly test the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. creating a get method of the has a Object (MS) in class PCService and then mock it.

```
public class PCService implements PCServiceIf {
    public MSIf getMS() {
        return ms;
    }

    private MSIf ms = new MS();
    public boolean isMovieAccessibleToMyLevel(String myLevel, String movieId)  {
        return  getMS().getPCL(movieId);
    }
}


@Test
public void testIsMovieAccessibleToMyLevelMock()  {
    msMock = mock(MS.class);
    spy  = spy(new PCService());

    doReturn(msMock).when(spy).getMS();
    when(msMock.getPCL(movieId)).thenReturn(value);
    when(spy.getMS().getPCL(movieId)).thenReturn(value);
    assertTrue(spy.isMovieAccessibleToMyLevel("PG", movieId) == true);
}
```